# Can't boot Ubuntu thumb drive

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have an old Eee PC T91 32bit notebook with Kali OS. I got Ubuntu loaded on a thumb drive, press F2, change boot options to the removable thumb drive, but the Kali version boots instead.

Comment: Just checking, do you have the 32 bit (i386) version of ubuntu on the thumb drive?

Comment: The existing OS is mostly irrelevant, where you want to replace it. I might recommend changing the title to something more like "Can't boot Ubuntu thumb drive".

Comment: ooops,  I'll double check that I've got the 32bit version...

Comment: I downloaded the corrected iso (32bit) and chose USB boot ... I only have the iso folder on the thumb drive....still no joy,  the kali loads instead.